# AVErrorMediaServicesWereReset when calling AVMutableCompositionTrack insertTimeRange

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, core-audio

I sometimes get the following error when I call

```
- (BOOL)insertTimeRange:(CMTimeRange)timeRange ofTrack:(AVAssetTrack *)track atTime:(CMTime)startTime error:(NSError **)error;
```

on an AVMutableCompositionTrack object.

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action" UserInfo=0x175dc750 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later., NSUnderlyingError=0x17534a00 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 268435459.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action}

According to the documentation, the error code -11819 represents AVErrorMediaServicesWereReset.
What does this mean in this context? Google did not find anything about this error in combination with the AVMutableCompositionTrack keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Apple and they actually confirmed that this is a bug in the firmware.